# Can´t connect Downstream device and Azure IOT Edge

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I am trying to connect a Leaf device(Raspberry Pi) to my IoT Edge Gateway. I followed the Microsoft documentation on how to install, setup and connect a transparent gateway and a downstream device with x509 certificate authentication.
Microsoft docu: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-transparent-gateway?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=iotedge + followed links in the section
Test Certificates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-test-certificates?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=windows

I translated the Hostname on the Raspberry with the IP Adress for the Gateway and i could successfully ping the gateway and open a ssl connection via

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect Gateway:8883 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text
```

Still after setting up everthing that is written in the guides i get the following message;

> Could not connect: mqtt.js returned Failure on first connection (Not authorized): unable to >verify the first certificate error

Here are the settings from my config.toml of the Edge Gateway:

```
hostname = "Gateway"  
    trust_bundle_cert = "file:///var/secrets/azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem"  
    ## Manual provisioning with X.509 certificate  
     [provisioning]  
     source = "manual"  
     iothub_hostname = "*AzureHubName*.azure-devices.net"  
     device_id = "Gateway"  
     [provisioning.authentication]  
     method = "x509"  
     identity_pk = "file:///var/secrets/iot-edge-device-identity-Gateway_primary.key.pem"                
     identity_cert = "file:///var/secrets/iot-edge-device-identity-Gateway_primary-full- 
     chain.cert.pem"        
     [edge_ca]  
     cert = "file:///var/secrets/iot-edge-device-Gateway_CA-full-chain.cert.pem"                  
     pk = "file:///var/secrets/iot-edge-device-Gateway_CA.key.pem"
```

Here is the module i am trying to use:

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.  
    // Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information.  
      
    'use strict';  
      
    // Choose a protocol by uncommenting one of these transports.  
    var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;  
    // var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-amqp').Amqp;  
    // var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-http').Http;  
    // var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').MqttWs;  
    // var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-amqp').AmqpWs;  
      
    var Client = require('azure-iot-device').Client;  
    var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;  
    var fs = require('fs');  
      
    // 1) Obtain the connection string for your downstream device and to it  
    //    append this string GatewayHostName=<edge device hostname>;  
   // 2) The Azure IoT Edge device hostname is the hostname set in the config.yaml of the Azure IoT Edge device  
    //    to which this sample will connect to.  
   //  
    // The resulting string should look like the following  
    //  "HostName=<iothub_host_name>;DeviceId=<device_id>;SharedAccessKey=   
    <device_key>;GatewayHostName=<edge device hostname>"  
    var deviceConnectionString = 'HostName=*AzureHubName*.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=SensorS;SharedAccessKey=Zf1zQXsEB1PowTnzti5PzKownXrwvP0x9oX4SH0PeTQ=;GatewayHostName=Gateway'>
     
    // Path to the Edge "owner" root CA certificate  
    var edge_ca_cert_path = '/home/pi/Certificates/azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem';  
      
    // fromConnectionString must specify a transport constructor, coming from any transport package.  
    var client = Client.fromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, Protocol);
     
   var sendInterval;  
    var connectCallback = function (err) {  
      if (err) {  
        console.error('Could not connect: ' + err.message);  
      } else {  
        console.log('Client connected');  
        client.on('message', function (msg) {  
          console.log('Id: ' + msg.messageId + ' Body: ' + msg.data);  
          // When using MQTT the following line is a no-op.  
          client.complete(msg, printResultFor('completed'));  
          // The AMQP and HTTP transports also have the notion of completing, rejecting or abandoning the message.  
          // When completing a message, the service that sent the C2D message is notified that the message has been processed.  
          // When rejecting a message, the service that sent the C2D message is notified that the 
    message won't be processed by the device. the method to use is>  
          // When abandoning the message, IoT Hub will immediately try to resend it. The method 
    to use is client.abandon(msg, callback).  
          // MQTT is simpler: it accepts the message by default, and doesn't support rejecting or 
    abandoning a message.  
        });  
      
        // Create a message and send it to the IoT Hub every two seconds  
        if (!sendInterval) {  
          sendInterval = setInterval(function () {
            var windSpeed = 10 + (Math.random() * 4); // range: [10, 14]
            var temperature = 20 + (Math.random() * 10); // range: [20, 30]
            var humidity = 60 + (Math.random() * 20); // range: [60, 80]
            var data = JSON.stringify({ deviceId: 'myFirstDownstreamDevice', windSpeed: 
    windSpeed, temperature: temperature, humidity: humidity });
            var message = new Message(data);
            message.properties.add('temperatureAlert', (temperature > 28) ? 'true' : 'false');
            console.log('Sending message: ' + message.getData());
            client.sendEvent(message, printResultFor('send'));
          }, 2000);
        }
    
        client.on('error', function (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
        });
    
        client.on('disconnect', function () {
          clearInterval(sendInterval);
          sendInterval = null;
          client.removeAllListeners();
          client.open(connectCallback);
        });
      }
    };
    
    // Provide the Azure IoT device client via setOptions with the X509
    // Edge root CA certificate that was used to setup the Edge runtime
    var options = {
      ca : fs.readFileSync(edge_ca_cert_path, 'utf-8'),
    };
    
    client.setOptions(options, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('SetOptions Error: ' + err);
      } else {
        client.open(connectCallback);
      }
    });
    
    // Helper function to print results in the console
    function printResultFor(op) {
      return function printResult(err, res) {
        if (err) console.log(op + ' error: ' + err.toString());
        if (res) console.log(op + ' status: ' + res.constructor.name);
      };
    }
```

I changed the var: deviceConnectionString and edge_ca_cert_path to match my settings.

I got absolutly no idea what i did wrong. Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "translating to IP address" and it's not clear if the child device could actually reach the IoT Edge device via "Gateway" as the hostname as you've shown in your `openssl` command.

To remove possible issues with local DNS/mDNS, try changing all of the values where you currently have "Gateway" for hostname (except for the device ID, leave that as is) to the *IoT Edge device* IP address. So

1. Change the `hostname` value in the config.toml to the IP address of the IoT Edge device.
2. To make sure `edgeHub` is properly recreated to ingest the new hostname value, run:

   ```
   sudo iotedge system stop && sudo docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq) && sudo iotedge config apply
   ```
3. To verify 1) connectivity from your child device to gateway and 2) that the IP addresses match between the connection and the certificate IoT Edge presents, run the `openssl` command your Raspberry Pi.

   ```
   echo | openssl s_client -connect <IoT Edge device IP address>:8883 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text
   ```

   You'd want to see that the subject CN matches the IP address like `Subject: CN = <IoT Edge device IP address>`.
4. With the connectivity and matching certificate, change the `GatewayHostName` on the Raspberry Pi device client to the IoT Edge device IP address also, recompile, and run it.

Comment: I executed all steps you suggested. The hostname was changed successfully and the ssl connection was successfull aswell, unfortunatly after i changed the hostname on the pi and run the application the same issue accured.